# In bootstrap table how to change the order of buttons

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Adding this attribute in the table tag is not working

data-buttons-order=['paginationSwitch','refresh','toggle','fullscreen','column']

Comment: Of course it won't work. You cannot assign 5 multiple values inside a dataset. You need to do it separately.

Comment: it is an attribute and it is an example from the documentation itself https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#buttonsorder

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found how to do :

In the `<table …>`, add this (by example) :

```
data-buttons-order="refresh, fullscreen, paginationSwitch, columns, advancedSearch, toggle"
```

(do not add `[…]` and `'…'`)

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/buttons-order.html) it is necessary to add `ul` element to add buttons. If you want to edit order, then you can edit just this list:

```
<ul id="sortable">      
  <li>refresh</li>
  <li>paginationSwitch</li>
  <li>toggle</li>
  <li>fullscreen</li>
  <li>columns</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

```
let $table = $('#table')

$table.bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
         columns: columns,
         data: data,
         buttonsOrder: ['btnName1','btnName2','btnName3']
   })
```